# how to reset game in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

My question in the previous post was-

> I have a cocos2d game, and after I
>   exit the game and start it again, it
>   starts at the exact same point it was
>   before closing.why this is
>   happening??and not only this, my game
>   is landscapemode but when I start it
>   again from simulator it comes in
>   portrait mode,not it landscapemode like
>   first time.
>
> Is there any way to prevent this?
>
> Anyone will come to rescue me???

I found a solution.Is it good??

when I exit the game(by pressing the back button in iPhone simulator) this problem occurred. Now I found that if I press back button the following function is called-

```
(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

So I set (divide by zero) or something like this in -(void)applicationWillResignActive function so that when this function called the application crashes. Then if I restart the application everything comes from beginning(reset) which I want. Is it good solution or anything better?

*my applicationDidFinishLaunching was not called again when application is restart from simulator.

Comment: Use  exit(0); inside (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure the Info.plist to indicate that you does not want your application run in Background.

The key is

> UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend

If you need more detail you should look at [this tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/multitasking/how-to-prevent-your-application-from-being-placed-into-the-background.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have iOS 4.0 or higher, multitasking is causing your problem.